# Update a column in access by code Java

Tags: java, database

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + s1);
        PreparedStatement s =conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *  FROM Table1", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);
        //ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
        int app1 = 0;
//        while (rs.next()) {
            rs.updateBoolean("collegato", true);
//            if (app1 == app) {
//                //  rs.updateBoolean("collegato", true);
//            }
//            app1 = app1 + 1;
//        }
        rs.close();
```

I want to be able to update my database by putting the `collegato` column to `true` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [updateBoolean(java.lang.String,boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) :

> The updater methods **do not** update the underlying database; instead the
>   updateRow or insertRow methods are called to update the database.

Call `rs.updateRow()` after you have updated the `ResultSet`, so that the actual database gets updated.